# CSS Center and Left Alignment Issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I need some help aligning two items, one in the top center and one on the top left. I have a parent div that contains both these items.

```
                <div className = {modalStyles.header}>
                    <span className = {modalStyles.close_button}onClick={()=>setIsOpen(false)}>Cancel</span>
                    <span className = {modalStyles.title}>Add to Playlist</span>
            </div>
```

The CSS code is:

```
.header{
padding-top: 25px;
padding-bottom: 25px;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
background-color: white;
}

.close_button{
display: inline-block;
color: #181B2C;
font-family: url('../../public/fonts/Lato-Bold.ttf');
font-size: 18px;
cursor: pointer;
margin: 25px;
}

.title{
display: inline-block;
color: #181B2C;
font-family: url('../../public/fonts/Lato-Bold.ttf');
font-size: 20px;
font-weight:600;
margin: auto;
}
```

The issue I'm having is that the title isn't being aligned correctly in the center of the header. It seems to be aligned relative to the close button.

Comment: Try setting the title to `flex: 0 0 95%` and `text-align: center`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use position relative to adjust it:

```
.title{
display: inline-block;
color: #181B2C;
font-family: url('../../public/fonts/Lato-Bold.ttf');
font-size: 20px;
font-weight:600;
margin: auto;
position: relative;
right: 25px; // same amount as left margin of close_button
}
```